How to retrieve return value of RUNEXE and also RUNSCRIPT?
In a macro file (*.do) in ALDEC Active-HDL 9.2, I am looking for a way to retrieve some kind of return value of an external executable (run by the runexe command).
So is there a way to retrieve the exit code, or to capture the console output (from stream STDOUT or even STDERR)?
Something like set return [runexe -wait -capture cmd /D /S /C exit 1]; echo $return does unfortunately not get the exit code 1, neither does set return [runexe -wait -capture cmd /D /S /C echo Result]; echo $return fetch the STDOUT output stream.
Do I miss something, or is something like that simply not supported?
If so, could such data be read from a (text) file as an alternative solution?
And by the way, is there a way to retrieve some kind of return value of a sub-macro (another *.do script run by the runscript command)?

If this is running in CMD on a windows machine (you have not told!), read up on the IF ERRORLEVEL DOS / BATCH command.

@Hannu, I'm talking about *.do macros, but not about the Windows Command Prompt. These macros run inside the Active-HDL application.

Ah, sorry, that was stated and my eyes skipped it. In my opinion the "runexe" you're using should provide such a feature. i guess you've already checked; Is there nothing about such things in the documentation?

@Hannu, unfortunately not, I searched the documentation and the web, but without success; perhaps someone else came across that issue and found a better solution than me…

The only work-around I found so far is to let the sub-executable write a variable definition statement to a temporary macro, like:
# write result to temporary `*.do` macro
# (`setenv` is needed instead of `set`):
runexe -wait -capture cmd /D /S /C {echo setenv var Test_1> temp.do}
# retrieve the resulting value:
runscript -do temp.do
echo $var
# clean up temporary macro:
runexe cmd /D /S /C del temp.do

